# Different Command prompt windows does not executing the same command

Tags: svn, cmd

I've two command prompt windows as follow,

> 1. Administrator:Command Prompt -- Opened manually

--

> 1. Administrator:C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe -- open by C# code
>      (Process.Start)

I'm trying to execute svn command, i.e consider `svn update` command.

This command executed successfully in the 1st cmd, which I opened manually.
But the same command does not executing in the 2nd cmd window, which is opened by C# code.

> Giving the error as "svn" is not recognized as internal or external
>   command

I want this to trigger from code. Checked path variables. 
Created a bat file to execute commands. The same error remains, executing the bat manually works while from code doesn't.

Why the cmd acts differently?

Comment: If you want to use Subversion from within a .NET application, it's better to integrate [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) into your code - don't spawn other processes to run other processes. Plus, adding the dependency on `svn.exe` just results in more stuff to have to manage and distribute.

Comment: @alroc, Thaks. from the code call, svn is not updating. So only went to bat file. But still its too not working. I purchased VisualSVN Server and Installed on my servers. Still I'll try with SharpSVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you checked the `%PATH%` variable, but you didn't say anything about how you checked it and what the result was. What do you get when you run `echo %PATH%` in the 2<sup>nd</sup> command window?

Given the error message it's almost certain that the path to the `svn` executable is missing from your `%PATH%`. Try the following:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\svn\dir
svn update
```

Comment: Thanks, I checked. The 2nd cmd is working if we're giving the commands manually . Its not working when called from the code.

Comment: Then it appears there's an issue with your code. Nothing much we can tell you without seeing it.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "svn update path_to_svn_dir");
and 
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:/file_path/name.bat"); both not worked. the bat file contains the command in first line.

Comment: I don't see you setting `PATH` in either of them.

Comment: Both are working perfect without settingup the path and If triggerd manually, BUT only not working with the code call.

Comment: If you want help, I suggest you start following the advice you're given. Otherwise you're on your own.