# Different command prompt window behaviors

Tags: c#, python, windows, batch-file, cmd

I've seen a very similar question asked before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208216/different-command-prompt-windows-does-not-executing-the-same-command), however the answer thread fell apart. Basically, I installed Python (and checked the option to add to the Path variable), confirmed that it is indeed in the path variable (through the Environment Variables window like you would normally).

When opening a cmd window manually, I can type python -V and get the version back, and anything else really, and everything works fine, python is indeed exposed through the command prompt (when opened manually).

However, when I attempt to run a command through cmd.exe with a C# app I have, I get

> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

The block of C# code I have

```
        var proc = new Process();
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            UseShellExecute = true,
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = "/K " + command
        };
        proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
        proc.Start();
```

This has worked fine in the past. However I had my work machine upgraded to Windows 10 and have been struggling to get this working.

The command text hasn't changed since the application was working before my windows upgrade, and if I take it's text and run it through a manually opened command prompt it executes fine with no issues. So I'm hesitant to believe it's an issue with the command itself.

UPDATE: If I run echo %PATH% in a regular prompt I see python, if I run it in the command prompt my application opens, I do not. I tried using set PATH, but that didn't help. Why is it that the PATH variable is different between a command prompt I open manually and one my application opens?

I thought it might have something to do with User and System variables having their own path, but Python is in both of them when checked via System Properties, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29878326/path-variable-different-when-cmd-was-run-through-the-context-menu) might be why. With UseShellExecute your cmd is inheriting a PATH from explorer.exe, but explorer.exe is using PATH from when windows booted, not from when you changed it. Answer there says "restart explorer", which they say you can do by logging out and back in.

Comment: Yup, a restart did it. Thanks so much! (Now that I feel dumb hah) 

This is again my work PC, and of course no matter how many times I offer they won't let me switch to SSD, so a restart is a whole ordeal, so I guess I've conditioned myself that it's not an option at work, normally that would've been the first thing I tried.

Comment: Python's old installer doesn't broadcast a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` "Environment" message to make Explorer reload its environment. The installer for 3.5 does implement this. Note that you don't need to log off. The control panel applet for modifying environment variables also broadcasts `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`, as does the command-line program setx.exe. Just make a small change to your user's environment, and then change it back, e.g. `setx PROMPT spam` followed by `setx PROMPT "%PROMPT%"`.

Comment: Interesting because I downloaded the 3.5.1 (I think, whatever is on the python download page as of a couple hours ago) when installing python,  I didn't use an old installer. Could be a bug with the installer with Windows 10?

Comment: Here's [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.1/Tools/msi/bundle/bootstrap/PythonBootstrapperApplication.cpp#l1084). If it successfully updates `PATH` for the system or user, then this code should broadcast the required `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message.